# Jenkins Artifactory Plugin - Maven wrapper not publishing custom artifacts which have been installed

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

When building my Maven project, I expect the [Jenkins Artifactory Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in) to deploy/publish artifacts which I successfully maven-install (ie, copied from the /target folder to my local maven repo).

The Jenkins-Artifactory plugin binds to the install phase of the Maven lifecycle.  It **is** publishing the pom files for the modules of my project, but **not** the build files I need (which I have installed).

**UPDATE:** JFrog have confirmed this is a bug with the plugin: https://github.com/jfrog/jenkins-artifactory-plugin/issues/665 - I will post an update to this question once it is resolved.

**PLEASE NOTE**: A normal pom which simply creates a jar works as expected.  This is specifically to do with publishing a custom artifact type having used the maven-install-plugin.

**Some details:**

- The build process creates **`.bar`** files
- These .bar files are added to `/target` using the `maven-install-plugin` execution shown below
- The .pom files are being uploaded to Artifactory
- The .bar files are not being uploaded to Artifactory

> ```
> <execution>
>   <id>custom-install</id>
>   <phase>install</phase>
>   <goals>
>       <goal>install-file</goal>
>   </goals>
>   <configuration>
>       <generatePom>true</generatePom>
>       <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
>       <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
>       <version>${project.version}</version>
>       <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.bar</file>
>       <packaging>bar</packaging>
>   </configuration>
> </execution>
> ```

**Logs:**

```
16:50:39  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file (custom-install) @ MyMavenModule ---
16:50:39  [main] INFO org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer - Installing /opt/jenkins/workspace/my-project/build/develop/2/MyMavenModule/target/MyMavenModule-1.0.0.bar to /home/jenkins-user/.m2/repository/my/project/group/MyMavenModule/1.0.0/MyMavenModule-1.0.0.bar
16:50:40  [pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.ArtifactoryManagerBuilder - [pool-1-thread-1] Deploying artifact: https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-local/my/project/group/MyMavenModule/1.0.0/MyMavenModule-1.0.0.pom
```

**Versions:**

- Jenkins: 2.332.1
- Artifactory: 6.16.0 Pro
- Jenkins Artifactory Plugin: 3.16.1
- Maven: 3.8.5
- Maven install plugin: 3.0.0-M1

**Pipeline / Plugin configuration**

```
rtMavenResolver (
        id: "resolver-${config.serverKey}",
        serverId: config.serverKey,
        releaseRepo: config.repos.resolve.release,
        snapshotRepo: config.repos.resolve.snapshot
)

rtMavenDeployer (
        id: "deployer-${config.serverKey}",
        serverId: config.serverKey,
        releaseRepo: config.repos.deploy.release,
        snapshotRepo: config.repos.deploy.snapshot,
        deployArtifacts : config.deployArtifacts,
        includePatterns: config.repos.deploy.includePatterns,
        excludePatterns: config.repos.deploy.excludePatterns,
        properties: config.repos.deploy.properties,
)

rtBuildInfo (
        captureEnv: true,
        buildName: config.buildName,
        buildNumber: config.buildNumber
)

def mvn(goals) {
    rtMavenRun (
            tool: config.tools.maven,
            pom: 'pom.xml',
            goals: "-U -e -B -V -Dstyle.color=always $goals",
            opts: '-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false -Djansi.force=true',
            deployerId: "deployer-${config.artifacts.serverKey}",
            resolverId: "resolver-${config.artifacts.serverKey}",
            buildName: config.artifacts.buildName,
            buildNumber: config.artifacts.buildNumber
    )
}

<<<snip>>>

mvn 'install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -DskipTests'
```

**Reproducible Example:**

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
        http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
        >
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyModule</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <exec-maven-plugin-version>1.6.0</exec-maven-plugin-version>
        <maven-install-plugin-version>3.0.0-M1</maven-install-plugin-version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        
        <!-- Note: See 'http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html' for details -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-install-plugin-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>custom-install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                            <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.bar</file>
                            <packaging>bar</packaging>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>Windows</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>Windows</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${exec-maven-plugin-version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>execution.compile.windows.buildBAR</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
                                    <executable>buildBAR.cmd</executable>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>${iib.toolkit.path.windows}</argument>
                                        <argument>${project.artifactId}</argument>
                                        <argument>${project.build.finalName}</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>unix</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>unix</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${exec-maven-plugin-version}</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>execution.compile.unix.buildBAR</id>
                                    <phase>compile</phase>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
                                        <executable>sh</executable>
                                        <arguments>
                                            <argument>buildBAR.sh</argument>
                                            <argument>${project.artifactId}</argument>
                                            <argument>${project.build.finalName}</argument>
                                        </arguments>
                                    </configuration>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>exec</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

buildBAR.cmd

```
SET moduleName=%1
SET barfileName=%2
echo %moduleName% > %barfileName%.bar
```

buildBAR.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
moduleName=$1
barfileName=$2
echo $moduleName > $barfileName.bar
```

`mvn clean install` yeilds:

```
PS C:\dev\barbuilder> mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.example:MyModule >------------------------
[INFO] Building MyModule 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ MyModule ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\dev\barbuilder\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (execution.compile.windows.buildBAR) @ MyModule ---

C:\dev\barbuilder\target>SET moduleName=MyModule 

C:\dev\barbuilder\target>SET barfileName=MyModule-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT      

C:\dev\barbuilder\target>echo MyModule  1>MyModule-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.bar 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:3.0.0-M1:install (default-install) @ MyModule ---
[INFO] Skipping artifact installation
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:3.0.0-M1:install-file (custom-install) @ MyModule ---
[INFO] Installing C:\dev\barbuilder\target\MyModule-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.bar to C:\Users\denham.coote\AppData\Local\.m2\repository\com\example\MyModule\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\MyModule-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.bar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\DENHAM~1.COO\AppData\Local\Temp\mvninstall1034342466988970935.pom to C:\Users\denham.coote\AppData\Local\.m2\repository\com\example\MyModule\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\MyModule-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.217 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-04-04T12:29:59+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
PS C:\dev\barbuilder>
```

Comment: I suspect the answer has something to do with registering these artifacts with the build info that is captured and used in order to publish to Artifactory, and not the install plugin directly.  I'm at a loss though!

Comment: It is very hard to construct a working example using the information you've provided. Could you provide a minimal reproducer?

Comment: I've seen a similar issue with CodeArtifact.  If you want to provide a minimal reproducible example I will take a stab at it

Comment: Given the parts involved, it's a little difficult, but I will try, yes.

Comment: @DenhamCoote Screenshot of Jenkins artifactory config would help answer your question.

Comment: @Smile I've added snippets to show how the plugin is used.  This works as expected for a normal "clean install" of something like a jar file.

Comment: You specify an include/exclude config there, are you sure this doesn't mess with *.bar files?

Comment: @Moro yeah, include is set to `"*"` and exclude to `""`. I have also tried explicitly including ".bar" which doesn't make any difference sadly.

Comment: JFrog have confirmed this is a bug with the plugin: https://github.com/jfrog/jenkins-artifactory-plugin/issues/665 - I will post an update to this question once it is resolved.